# No account is found

Tags: ibm-cloud

I login to bluemix through my IBM id. Today one of my colleagues added me to his account so that we can jointly develop an application. But since then it seems my account is deleted. When I login to bluemix dashboard, in the region, org, space drop downs, there are no data. shown When I click on other links on the page like Support/Manage etc, the page just loads indefinitely.

In fact when I login through command line and then execute:

`bx account list`

It says, 

`Retrieving all accounts of XXXXXX@XX.ibm.com...
OK
No account is found`

I still have the account GUID of my account. When I try to:

`bx target -c XXXX`

it says,

`FAILED
Could not target account.
BSS Account  was not found.`

Does that mean my account is deleted?!? If so, then how can I get it back?

Answer (score 0):

Ask to the colleague who invited you to remove your account from his org or you can get yourself out of an account,  you have to use a BX command line CLI.

With the BX CLI you can:

```
$ bx account org-user-remove 
NAME: 
   org-user-remove - Remove a user from org (org manager or user him/herself only) 
USAGE: 
   bx account org-user-remove USER_NAME ORG [-f, --force] 
OPTIONS: 
   --force, -f  Force deletion without confirmation
```

Check to see if your account is repaired.

Take the test described if it does not solve I suggest you open a ticket at the bluemix support

Comment: He already removed me from his org. I created a support case at IBM Cloud Service Desk. My account is a free one, so not sure when it will be picked up by the IBM team.